# What is the first Sloka in Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, valmiki

Valmiki keeps on wondering about Maanishada... sloka and Brahma says it is Saraswathi's grace and it is considered as the first sloka. Then what about the conversation between Sage Narada and Valmiki, that starts with Tapah Swadhyay Niratam..., is that not the first sloka?